# Air 14.0 Worker isSupported returns false in Android

Tags: android, air, worker

I am using Nexus 4 to test the app. I have build it using Flash Builder 4.6
I am able to run the app without any problem on Desktop .
But when I try it on my mobile it gives false for Worker.isSupported .

I have installed Air 14.0 on my mobile and android version is 4.4.4

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I missed flex compiler setting `-swf-version=22`

By default if you compile using flash builder it will return isSupported = false because swf version needs to be 22 and above.
One have to explicitly mention it in flex compiler settings.